# Design Documents for Python/Django?

Tags: django, documentation

After working on a Django project for a while, I now have to do some design documents for it (UML type stuff). However the code doesn't have classes, but instead uses `views.py` with modules in it...

What would be the best way to show the design of my application from the initial `__init__.py`, to the `urls.py` where the HTML requests are then filtered to the specific `urls.py` in each of the packages and then handled by the `views.py`?

i.e.

```
django-app
    urls.py
    views.py
    settings.py
    manager.py
    __init__.py
    django-package
        urls.py
        views.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django doesn't map properly to class diagrams. Skip that part and go with the other diagrams.

Comment: Any recommendations? I was considering just making it up as I go along, however I'd like to use some sort of recognised format?

Comment: *The Unified Modeling Language User Guide* section 6, "Architectural Modeling".

Comment: Thanks a lot. I shall be taking this out at the library! :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried django-command extensions?. That is useful to generate a graphical overview of your models, and it belong to your design documents.

http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/wiki/GraphModels